# How to set system properties in gradle when running a project via command line?

Tags: java, gradle

I tried `gradle run -DdatabaseHost="127.0.0.1"` in command line, but when use `System.out.println("databaseHost: " + System.getProperty("databaseHost"));` to print it out the outcome is `null`.

But when I use

```
System.setProperty("databaseHost", "127.0.0.1");
```

the outcome is `127.0.0.1`, which is correct.

I am wondering what is wrong with the `gradle run -DdatabaseHost="127.0.0.1"` command?

Could anyone help me please?
Thanks!

Update:
`-P` doesn't work either I am afraid, the same goes for `--args`, as shown below:

`-P`: [image]

`--args`: [image]

In my main method the property is printed out as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you need a single like to added:

```
systemProperties System.properties
```

probably in the `run` task.